# jwchat integration with opnefire on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, openfire

I am working to integrate tomcat+jwchat & connect it with openfire.I followed following steps:

- Installed openfire 3.7.0.exe  on port 9090.
- Installed tomcat on port 8080.
- Downloaded jwchat.war & put it inside webapps folder of tomcat.
- Mentioned following entry into server.xml under conf folder of tomcat

`Context Path="/jwchat" docBase="jwchat" debug="0" privileged="true"/>`

1. Put following entry in config.js of jwchat

   var SITENAME = "localhost";

where openfire is installed using localhost as server name.

```
var BACKENDS =    
[    
{    
name:"Open Relay",    
description:"HTTP Binding backend",    
httpbase:"/jwchat",    
type:"binding",    
default_server: SITENAME    
}    
];
```

Finally i started openfire & then jwchat separately on separate servers and used following url

```
http://localhost:8080/jwchat
```

I can see login page of jwchat but whenever i am trying to login, it is not able to login & i am redirected again to login page.

I am stuck up here & googled a lot but could not find anything relevant.

Please help me here.

P.S. I found a lot of articles talking about apache+jwcat integration like [this](http://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Integrating_Jabber_%28Wildfire,_jwchat,_%20MUCkl%29), but nothing around tomcat+jwchat integration. Is jwchat not being used with tomcat or is it obsolete to be used now a days?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an HTTP polling binder, like JHB installed and verify your

```
var SITENAME = "localhost";
```

is same as the openfire `servername`